How to get token transaction history with sold tokens in specific time range amout in Solana blockchain?
Could someone please guide me on how to retrieve transaction history along with the bought token amounts on the Solana blockchain? Like it is in Dexscrener? .png example below
I want to get that information in .js but I do not know where to start, I see that helium does have transaction history api, but how should I proceed that it show last transaction history in specifi time range of token and amount bought?

I did tried using helium, but it does only show me transaction history of wallets
